# How to deploy changes for postgres with NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a nodeJS app with PostgreSQL database.
I've modified source code, and now, to deploy it i'll need to deploy source code to server from git repo. Changes will be applied, server will be restarted and that's all.
Is there similar approach for deploying Postgres changes? Or i'll always need to manually write bunch of queries, which will modify database schema?

Comment: Third party-tool and offsite resource ... Search for "*nodejs database migration*" and you'll find a couple of tools.

Comment: never thought I'll recommend it and I don't, but http://sqitch.org/ is close to git philosophy of postgres deployments